# Retrieving data from Oracle databases in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I wanted to use multiple Joins to pull the data from an Oracle database.

I have created a link between SQL Server and the Oracle database. The query works fine when I only join one table I am trying to join the multiply table it won't work.

Sample query is below.

```
select a.*,b.po_no1,c.* 
from 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(po_no, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', po_no) > 0 THEN 
    CHARINDEX('-', po_no)-1 ELSE LEN(po_no)
                                END) po_no1
FROM intext
WHERE rec_status = 'NEW') b 

left join

 (select * from openquery(DW,'SELECT po_no,order_no
               FROM purchaseorder')) a on a.po_no = b.po_no1
right join
(select * from openquery(DW,'SELECT po_no,order_no
               FROM salesorder')) c on a.po_no = c.po_no
               where a.po_no is not null
```

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL?

Comment: Could you also add an error message . or what it means won't work

Comment: It is not giving me any error as such but when I check after 8 hours it is still executing. if I run the first 2 tables it will give me output within 8 mins

Comment: There also appears to be a syntax error with table ```b```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create all the joins on the oracle side (to have a final table), and then just query the whole table from MS SQL.